# PayPal REST API return empty payer_info for non US accounts

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

I am using the PayPal REST API, and when it returns to confirm & execute the payment, I'd like to retrieve payer information such as name, address, phone, etc from their PayPal account for creating local order in DB, etc.

I take the PP payer info from the [ [payer_info](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#payerinfo-object) ] and usually everything works well. Here is an example of what I get in a normal situation (for api.sandbox.paypal.com):

```
[id] = PAY-9J918741MY200351GKOI7PUI
[create_time] = 2014-06-06T17:18:09Z
[update_time] = 2014-06-06T17:18:52Z
[state] = approved
[intent] = sale
[payer] =>
    [payment_method] = paypal
    [payer_info] =>
        [email] = admin@xiaose.me
        [first_name] = Denis
        [last_name] = Silinsky
        [payer_id] = PWHQN5FK5N8LN
        [shipping_address] =>
            [line1] = 1 Maire-Victorin
            [line2] = 
            [city] = Toronto
            [state] = Ontario
            [postal_code] = M5A 1E1
            [country_code] = CA
            [recipientName] =
```

But now all time happens, almost in all (90%) cases, I get a blank [ [payer_info](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#payerinfo-object) ], if a person pays from Canada or Australia. Here's an example of what I get:

```
[id] = PAY-98X74297DD864450EKOJAT7Y
[create_time] = 2014-06-06T18:35:43Z
[update_time] = 2014-06-06T18:36:38Z
[state] = approved
[intent] = sale
[payer] =>
    [payment_method] = paypal
    [payer_info] =>
        [shipping_address] =>
```

I even created a test account specifically for Canada (before I tested with the US account), but in the test mode, everything is OK and necessary data regularly comes, but no necessary data as soon as the order creates by a real customer with an address outside of US.

How to deal with all this?

Where else I can get this data ( http://www.dropmocks.com/mFO2a5 )?

[image: it's info from my log file where you can see that some time no payer info]

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you solve this?

Comment: No. Nothing has been fixed until now. I called into their tech support, thay admitted that there is a problem, passed to programmers to fix it but solve nothing until now...